# Trying to use :not() for custom cursor, not working

Tags: html, css

I have a sliding tray nav that comes in from the left, when on the body of my page, if the user isn't active over that `div` I'd like to show a custom close cursor only I'm struggling to get it working.

```
.display-cs :not(#cs-index) { 
  cursor: pointer;
  //url('../img/icons/close-cross.png'), default; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/38gdp4pb/1/

I've tried just reverting to cursor:pointer to no avail, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Update**

My body has the class `.display-cs` and `#cs-index` is a menu on the page. I want the custom cursor to appear on the page but not within `#cs-index`

Comment: Remove the space from your selector: `.display-cs:not(#cs-index)`

Comment: It seems to be working, what is your problem? If I had another div inside your nav it will have a cursor pointer while your cs-index div does not

Comment: _“I don't want the cursor to appear when hovering over #cs-index”_ - then you need to explicitly specify a _different_ cursor for `#cs-index`, because `cursor` is one of the properties that get inherited. `:not` won’t help you one bit here, because `#cs-index` does not have the cursor applied because your rule selected that element, but because it inherits the cursor from its parent.

Comment: `.display-cs:not(#cs-index) { 
  cursor: none;
  //url('../img/icons/close-cross.png'), default; 
}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER AFTER COMMENT OF OP:

You could simply overwrite it with a seperate rule:

```
.display-cs {
  cursor: pointer;
  //url('../img/icons/close-cross.png'), default; 
}

#cs-index {
  padding: 10rem;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dgroucag/

Comment: I don't want the cursor to appear when hovering over #cs-index but this allows that?

Comment: Does not much more sense with the given HTML code either, though ... the `#cs-index` is a child of the only `.display-cs` element there, so for that HTML this selects exactly the same elements as just `.display-cs` would have to begin with.

Comment: Look in the fiddle, `#cs-index` is **in** `.display-cs`

Comment: this is wrong,you vote to reputation or correct answer?

Comment: @ehsan I was writing about the selector, why should that be wrong? `:not...`  alone wouldn't make any sense, it has to be appended to something, at least to `*`

Comment: @Sfili_81 That is what OP already have. The global selector doesn't change anything, as when omitted, it works the same

Comment: I've updated my question - I didn't explain it clearly enough.

Comment: Why don't you just overwrite it with an according rule, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/dgroucag/

Comment: I've used it in wrong context, i mean you must use like this p:not();

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `:not()` to select parent and not specific children, instead you need to define specific rule to get default pointer on child element.

```css
.display-cs {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
#cs-index {
  cursor: initial;
}
#cs-index {
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-cs">
  <div class="nav" id="cs-index">This is my nav</div>
  asdasd
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my question - I didn't explain it clearly enough.

Comment: Still the same answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

you no need to `not`,just overlap it with `#cs-index{cursor:auto;}`

```css
.display-cs {
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFF;
}

#cs-index {
   background-color: red;
   cursor: auto;
   padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-cs">
   <div class="nav" id="cs-index">cs-index</div>
    display-cs
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my question - I didn't explain it clearly enough.

Comment: @Liam , red color is ` #cs-index` and blue is  `display-cs`.

Comment: @Liam , check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
.display-cs { 
    cursor: pointer;
}

#cs-index {
padding:10rem;
background:red;
color:#fff;
cursor:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-cs">

<div class="nav" id="cs-index">This is my nav</div>
asdasd
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css:

```
.display-cs *:not(#cs-index) { 
    cursor: pointer;
}
#cs-index {
    padding:10rem;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    cursor: default;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="display-cs">
    <div class="nav" id="cs-index">This is my nav</div>
    <div>
        asd1
    </div>
    <div>
        asd2
    </div>
</div>
```

This will put a pointer cursor on any element block that does not have the id `#cs-index`